# Loop for two variables

Tags: windows, loops, powershell, export-to-csv

I have the following ps1 file (script below, unfortunately it must be PowerShell, not anything easier), running a `curl` request, taking a piece of it out to a file, then running some text replacements.

```
$url = "https://someserver/trans="
$transaction = "1" #There are 4 transactions
$node = "node1" #There are 10 nodes

Remove-Item ATM.csv -Force

# So far so good
# Below is what I'd use as a function in bash. No sure what/how to do in PS:
#OUTPUT:

echo $transaction";"$node >> ATM.csv
curl -v -k -u user@pass $url$transaction$node | findstr "<value>" >> ATM.csv
(Get-Content ATM.csv) -replace "<value>"," " | Out-File ATM.csv
(Get-Content ATM.csv) -replace "</value>"," " | Out-File ATM.csv
(Get-Content ATM.csv) -replace " ","" | Out-File ATM.csv
```

The script as it is gives me one transaction value (Three rows in the csv: the transaction, the node, and a number). In practice I'd need to use an array or list with 10 machines, and 4 different transactions.

My problem is setting up a loop for two variables, I need to run the OUTPUT part 40 times (4 transactions X 10 nodes). I've done similair stuff in Python, bash but I find myself baffled and out of time in PowerShell. I spent hours running around the web and trying non-working examples.

Could you gimme a hand?

Comment: That is not how you would handle these things in PowerShell. At all. Please provide sample `curl` output (unfiltered), and the desired CSV output you want to create from it.

Comment: Additionally, `-replace` uses regex

Comment: What does the URL look like when it's done, `https://serv/trans=1node1`?

Comment: Your code says 4 transactions 10 nodes, while the text states it vice versa? To process the html/xml/json return there are better methods than using findstr.exe. [edit] your question to contain a verbose return and your expected csv end result with ? `;` delimiter.

Comment: @LotPings - 4 transactions 10 nodes, fixed the error in the text :-)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers , You're absolutely right, I'm trying to replace a batch file in a windows system. I'd totally use sed if I could. What's the equivalent for that in Powershell?

Comment: If you want to use `sed`, use [`sed`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm). If you want to use PowerShell, provide the information I requested, so that we may suggest a proper PowerShell solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added an s to your variables and then assumed the first "transactions" would need to be in the outerloop:

```
$url = "https://someserver/trans="
$transactions = '1','2','3','4' #There are 4 transactions
$nodes = 'node1','node2','node3','node4','node5','node6' #There are 10 nodes

Remove-Item ATM.csv -Force

# So far so good
# Below is what I'd use as a function in bash. No sure what/how to do in PS:
#OUTPUT:
foreach($transaction in $transactions)
{
    foreach($node in $nodes)
    {
    "$transaction;$node" |out-file -Append ATM.csv
    curl -v -k -u user@pass $url$transaction$node | findstr "<value>" | out-file -Append ATM.csv
    (Get-Content ATM.csv) -replace "<value>"," " | Out-File -Append ATM.csv
    (Get-Content ATM.csv) -replace "</value>"," " | Out-File -Append ATM.csv
    (Get-Content ATM.csv) -replace " ","" | Out-File -Append ATM.csv
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest changing the external call to `& 'path\to\curl.exe'` and if it's `PSv3`+, `& 'path\to\curl.exe' --%`

Comment: Or instead of curl use Invoke-webrequest

Comment: Thanks, I got the Get-Content part out of the loop and added Stop-Process to ps at the end of the script, otherwise the whole thing hangs if run more than once.

Answer (score 1):

I still think the best way to handle curl output would be to parse with the object type it returns (html/xml/json).

When parsing text output I'd then use a regular expression. PowerShell supports [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) so this script (with reversed node transaction order):

```
## Q:\Test\2017\09\13\SO_46179493.ps1
$url = "https://someserver/trans="
$transactions = 1..4|ForEach-Object{"$_"}       #There are 4 transactions
$nodes = 1..10|ForEach-Object{"node{0}" -f $_}  #There are 10 nodes
$RE = [RegEx]'(?<=\<value\>).+(?=\<\/value\>)'
# The RE uses lookbehind and lookahead to assert the captured value is surrounded by
# the tags <value> and </value>

$ATM = ForEach($node in $nodes){
    ForEach($transaction in $transactions) {
      curl -v -k -u user@pass $url$transaction$node | Where-Object {$_ -match $RE}|
        ForEach-Object {[pscustomobject]@{
          node = $node
          transaction = $transaction
          value = $Matches[0]}
        }
    }
}
$ATM
$ATM | Export-Csv '.\ATM.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Will produce this (simulated) display:

```
node   transaction value
----   ----------- -----
node1  1           79719
node1  2           77829
node1  3           90337
node1  4           39470
...
node10 1           17294
node10 2           62468
node10 3           70542
node10 4           46147
```

and file output:

```
> cat .\ATM.csv
"node","transaction","value"
"node1","1","79719"
"node1","2","77829"
"node1","3","90337"
"node1","4","39470"
...
"node10","1","17294"
"node10","2","62468"
"node10","3","70542"
"node10","4","46147"
```

Comment: TL;DR and the problem was solved with findstr and value.Replace calls, but for future use - how would I parse an xml with powershell? The curl returns a bunch of <bla>something</bla> lines and I only need the number from the line: <value>number</value>.